# loop through a list, compare element in front and element behind

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a function to validate a list.

Basically, for any given element in a list, either the item in front of it, or the item behind it has to be the same.

A good list is defined as:

`good_list = ["H", "H", "H", "M", "M", "L", "L", "M", "M", "H", "H", "H"]`

A bad list is defined as:

`bad_list = ["H", "M", "H", "M", "M", "L", "L", "M", "M", "H", "H", "H"]`

I've spent a couple days trying different solutions (and reading on stackoverflow) and below is what I currently have, but it is not returning the right answer.  Based on the feedback (thanks!), I've updated it and changed the name of the argument from list to season and made it an OR.  It is still returning a "valid list" when it shouldn't though?

```
bad_list = ["H", "M", "H", "M", "M", "L", "L", "M", "M", "H", "H", "H"]

def check_list(season):     
   for i, a in enumerate(season):
        if season[i] == season[i-1] or season[i] == season[i+1]:
            return True
   return False

result = check_list(bad_list)

if result == True:
    print "Valid list"
else:
    print "Invalid list"
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `list` because it is already a function. 2. You should check the bounds of your list before accessing things that are potentially out of bounds; remember that Python allows negative indices which may not be desirable here. 3. `and` should be `or`, or else the entire list would have to be the same element.

Comment: thanks for the help, I changed it to 'or', but it is still returning valid list for bad list, when it should be invalid?

Answer (score 4):

I'd simply use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
if all(len(tuple(group)) > 1 for key, group in itertools.groupby(the_list)):
    print "valid"
else:
    print "invalid"
```

Basically the request "each element should have an equal element right before or after it" is equivalent to "the list must be composed of groups of consecutive elements of minimum length 2". The `groupby` function makes these groups, and you simply have to check `all` their lengths are bigger than `1`.

Comment: nice trick. don't know if this actually work, i take it it does, but explicit and readbililty is important.

Comment: @CppLearner Well, I think it *is* readable. I mean: `all` -> condition that must be satisfied by all the elements, `groupby` groups equal elements, `len(tuple(group)) > 1` every group of consecutive equal elements must be of at least 2 elements, meaning that every element in the list has either a predecessor or successor equal to itself.

Comment: and I just forced you to explain it. hahaha. mind to put that in your answer? :D i know it's opinionated. just 0.00001 cents.

Comment: You can always break the `groupby` call, the generator expression, and the `all` call up into separate lines. (And by "you" I mean @CppLearner, the person who's having trouble understanding it—Bakuriu shouldn't be expected to break up perfectly readable and idiomatic code.) Then, if you don't understand what one of the three lines does, you can ask a specific question instead of just saying "explain this".

Comment: @abarnert I don't want to open a flame war. Let's be reasonable. The for loop is still far better readable. At any day I can look at the for loop and understand what it does. I understand itertools and I use it all the time. I am pointing out the obvious - if OP was using for-loop, give it a for-loop solution. An altnerative is nice, but shouldn't deserve higher vote.

Comment: @CppLearner: I disagree that the for loop is more readable, and I assume Bakuriu does as well. When the code is so complicated that the loop boilerplate is only 10% of the verbiage and the genexp is hard to parse in your head, the loop obviously wins—but in the same way, when the code is trivial enough that the loop boilerplate is the majority of the code (meaning you have to put extra thought into reading the actual meaning out of the code) and the genexp is a simple one-liner, I think the genexp wins. If that weren't true, Guido wouldn't have added comprehensions and genexps to the language.

Comment: @CppLearner: Also, nobody is downvoting your answer or saying that it's no good. It's perfectly fine, and it's worth having as another answer here.

Comment: @abarnert I didn't downvote him at all. :) I was merely trying to be funny by encouraging him to supply explanation. We can probably come up with the same solution using other more absurd Python code. But throwing the code and no explanation wasn't helpful so I asked him to provide some. I still hold my stand on loop being better. With a line documentation, I can spot the real usage without having to know what groupby does.

Comment: From a newbie perspective, the loop is much easier to understand (and to learn from).  I do appreciate learning other ways it can be done, but can't see myself using this solution anytime in the current future until my skills improve and I get a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code use `or` instead of and:

```
if list[i] == list[i-1] or list[i] == list[i+1]:
```

Also you should only perform these checks if the indices `i-1` and respectively `i+1` do not "fall out" of the list.

This is by far not the best performing solution but should work.

I will not fix your code as I guess you are supposed to come up with it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

For the more general case of 'comparing element in front and element behind', I would use `itertools.tee` and `itertools.izip` -- perhaps gathering the follow pattern into a utility function.

Also, the logic in your loop is inside-out.

```
# (inside the function)
_behind, _current, _ahead = itertools.tee(the_list, 3)
# should error check as well
_current.next()
_ahead.next()
_ahead.next()
for behind, current, ahead in itertools.izip(_behind, _current, _ahead):
    # fixing logic here
    if behind != current and current != ahead:
        return False
return True
```

or

```
return not any(behind != current and current != ahead for behind, current, ahead in itertools.izip(_behind, _current, _ahead))
```

Note that you'll need to handle 1-length and 2-length lists with a special case.

Comment: I think it should be `itertools.tee(the_list, 3)`, otherwise you'd get a `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`.

Comment: oops, I was thinking of that when I wrote it but forgot to put it in. Fixed.